# Overlaying, resizing and repositioning an image

Tags: android

Hey there I am developing an android app to add filters i am first getting the images from gallery and camera the i am overlaying another image in same image view but the problem is this that the image i overlayed is of fixed size. I want to resize and reposition it during run time. Watch this video for reference 
https://youtu.be/kGbvO--RDwU

I just need your suggestions. I have overlayed the image perfectly. Now i just need to resize, repostion or rotate that image on run time

Comment: you can use ConstraintLayout in layout and in body add imageView that attribute of this added below lines
layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

Comment: then what next ... i need to rotate resize and reposition the image just like in video